# Compare two dataframes column values. Find which values are in one df and not the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, data-mining

I have the following dataset

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michalis0/DataMining_and_MachineLearning/master/data/sales.csv')
df["OrderYear"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Order Date']).year
```

I want to compare the customers in 2017 and 2018 and see if the store has lost customers.

I did two subsets corresponding to 2017 and 2018 :

```
Customer_2018 = df.loc[(df.OrderYear == 2018)]
Customer_2017 = df.loc[(df.OrderYear == 2017)]
```

I then tried to do this to compare the two :

```
Churn = Customer_2017['Customer ID'].isin(Customer_2018['Customer ID']).value_counts()
Churn
```

And i get the following output :

```
True     2206
False     324
Name: Customer ID, dtype: int64
```

The problem is some customers may appear several times in the dataset since they made several orders.
I would like to get only unique customers (`Customer ID` is the only unique attribute) and then compare the two dataframes to see how many customers the store lost between 2017 and 2018.

Comment: can you give the inbetween steps to get df.OrderYear? Because there is only 'Order Date' in the columns.

Comment: Oh sorry here it is ```df["OrderYear"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Order Date']).year```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one comparison is required, I would use python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
c2017 = set(Customer_2017['Customer ID'])
c2018 = set(Customer_2018['Customer ID'])
print(f'lost customers between 2017 and 2018: {len(c2017 - c2018)}')
print(f'customers from 2017 remaining in 2018: {len(c2017 & c2018)}')
print(f'new customers in 2018: {len(c2018 - c2017)}')
```

output:

```
lost customers between 2017 and 2018: 83
customers from 2017 remaining in 2018: 552
new customers in 2018: 138
```

###### building on the `crosstab` suggestion from @Corralien:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Customer ID'], df['OrderYear'])
(out.gt(0).astype(int).diff(axis=1)
    .replace({0: 'remained', 1: 'new', -1: 'lost'})
    .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
)
```

output:

```
OrderYear  2015  2016  2017  2018
lost        NaN   163   123    83
new         NaN   141   191   138
remained    NaN   489   479   572
```

Answer (score 2):

To go further in the analysis, you can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Customer ID'], df['OrderYear'])
```

At this point your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> out
OrderYear    2015  2016  2017  2018
Customer ID                        
AA-10315        4     1     4     2
AA-10375        2     4     4     5
AA-10480        1     0    10     1
AA-10645        6     3     8     1
AB-10015        4     0     2     0  # <- lost customer
...           ...   ...   ...   ...
XP-21865       10     3     9     6
YC-21895        3     1     3     1
YS-21880        0     5     0     7
ZC-21910        5     9     9     8
ZD-21925        3     0     5     1
```

Values are the number of order per customer and year.

Now it's easy to get "lost customers":

```
>>> sum((out[2017] != 0) & (out[2018] == 0))
83
```

Comment: Welcome! I like that you show a general way to list customer's involvement for earch year. While the `set()` solution is the one one thinks of first.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim yes crosstab is quite nice (+1 btw), you can even go the next step. I added an example as your liked it (cf. [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875740/16343464)) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use normal sets to get unique customer ids for each year and then subtract them appropriately:

```
set_lost_cust = set(Customer_2017["Customer ID"]) - set(Customer_2018["Customer ID"])
len(set_lost_cust)

Out: 83
```

For your original approach to work you would need to drop the duplicates from the DataFrames, to make sure each customer appears only a single time:

```
Customer_2018 = df.loc[(df.OrderYear == 2018), ​"Customer ID"].drop_duplicates()
Customer_2017 = df.loc[(df.OrderYear == 2017), ​"Customer ID"].drop_duplicates()

Churn = Customer_2017.isin(Customer_2018)
Churn.value_counts()

#Out: 
True     552
False     83
Name: Customer ID, dtype: int64
```